# I can't access individual members from an array populated from table object

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, excel-tables, listobject

I am populating an array from a row of a table. I am able to print the entire array, but I am not able to print a member or iterate the array independently as shown in the following images:

**Image 1)** the array is printed

[image]

**Image 2)** the subscript is out of range

[image]

As also seen on the image here is the code:

```
Sub try_w()
    Dim H_PR() As Variant
        
    H_PR_dim = Worksheets("COV_CHOL").ListObjects("Historical_PR").ListRows(1).Range.Count
    ReDim H_PR(H_PR_dim)
        
    H_PR = Worksheets("COV_CHOL").ListObjects("Historical_PR").ListRows(1).Range.Value
    '1.a.2)
    'Try
    Worksheets("H_PRi").Range("B2:E2") = H_PR
    'Try end/PASS
    'Try
    Worksheets("H_PRi").Range("B3") = H_PR(1)
    'Try end/FAIL
End Sub
```

Comment: Individual element of a 2D array can be accessed as `array(rownumber,columnnumber)` As you have only one row, if you want the first element, then H_Rr(1,1) and second with H_Pr(1,2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Writing from Range to Array

- Using variables makes the code more readable (understandable).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub try_w()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code

    ' Source

    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("COV_CHOL")
    Dim stbl As ListObject: Set stbl = sws.ListObjects("Historical_PR")
    
    ' Range
    
    ' This is a one-row range.
    Dim srrg As Range: Set srrg = stbl.ListRows(1).Range
    ' Number of columns
    'Dim cCount As Long: cCount = srrg.Columns.Count
    ' Number of rows
    'Dim rCount As Long: rCount = srrg.Rows.Count
    
    ' Array
    
    ' You can write the data from a range using the following line.
    ' You don't need the number of rows or columns.
    Dim srData As Variant: srData = srrg.Value
    ' Note that this works only if there are at least two cells in the range!
    ' See the function below on how to do it properly.
    
    ' Number of columns
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = UBound(srData, 2)
    ' Number of rows
    'Dim rCount As Long: rCount = UBound(srData, 1)

    ' Destination
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("H_PRi")
    '1.a.2)
    'Try
    dws.Range("B2").Resize(, cCount).Value = srData
    ' or 
    'dws.Range("B2").Resize(1, cCount).Value = srData
    ' or without cCount:
    'dws.Range("B2").Resize(, UBound(Data, 2)).Value = srData
    ' Note that the default of both 'Resize' arguments is '1' i.e.
    ' Range("B2").Resize(1, 1) is Range("B2"), while
    ' Range("B2").Offset(0, 0) is Range("B2").
    
    'Try end/PASS
    'Try
    dws.Range("B3").Value = srData(1, 1)
    dws.Range("B4").Value = srData(1, 2)
    dws.Range("B5").Value = srData(1, 3)
    dws.Range("B6").Value = srData(1, 4)
    'Try end/FAIL
    
    ' Note that this is just practice. The array is redundant here
    ' because you can simply do...
'    dws.Range("B2").Resize(, cCount).Value = srrg.Value
'    dws.Range("B3").Value = srrg.Cells(1)
'    dws.Range("B4").Value = srrg.Cells(2)
'    dws.Range("B5").Value = srrg.Cells(3)
'    dws.Range("B6").Value = srrg.Cells(4)
    ' which is called 'copying by assignment'.

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the values of a range in a 2D one-based array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetRange( _
    ByVal rg As Range) _
As Variant
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    Dim rData As Variant
    If rg.Rows.Count + rg.Columns.Count = 2 Then
        ReDim rData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): rData(1, 1) = rg.Value
    Else
        rData = rg.Value
    End If

    GetRange = rData
End Function

    ' In our previous example, we can utilize the function like this:
    'Dim srData As Variant: srData = GetRange(srrg)
```